# Inserting a string inside of a regex match

Tags: python, regex, string, match

I need to insert the string `Special:MyLanguage/` into strings like `[[ACBDEF]]` so it becomes `[[Special:MyLanguage/ABCDEF]]`.

The problem is, that I need to exclude certain matches where it should not insert the `Special:MyLanguage/`:

- strings already containing `Special:MyLanguage/`or
- `Category:` or
- `File:`or
- `Image:`

So replacing `\[\[` with `\[\[Special:MyLanguage/` does unfortunately not work. Also, replacing `\[\[[^(Special:MyLanguage|File:|Image:|Category:)]` does not work, because it includes the first character (a match would be `[[A`). I've read a lot of tutorials, experimented around with `$1` and `\G` and such things, but am still scratching my head.

Comment: FYI, Python `re` does not support `\G` and the replacement backreference syntax is `\n` or `\g<n>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a negative lookahead to make sure those substrings do not occur right after `[[`:

```
(\[\[)(?!Special:MyLanguage/|File:|Image:|Category:)(.*?]])
```

and replace with `\1Special:MyLanguage/\2`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xTMugZ/1).

**Details**

- `(\[\[)` - Group 1: `[[` substring
- `(?!Special:MyLanguage/|File:|Image:|Category:)` - the `[[` can't be followed with any of the substrings listed in the alternation group
- `(.*?]])` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, followed with `]]`.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/50f5S6):

```
import re
rx = r"(\[\[)(?!Special:MyLanguage/|File:|Image:|Category:)(.*?]])"
s = "[[Special:MyLanguage/text]]\n[[File:text]]\n[[Image:text]]\n[[Category:text]]\n[[Text and ]]"
res = re.sub(rx, r"\1Special:MyLanguage/\2", s)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[Special:MyLanguage/text]]
[[File:text]]
[[Image:text]]
[[Category:text]]
[[Special:MyLanguage/Text and ]]
```

Comment: I would recommend editing the `.*?` to a `[^\]]*` to make the regex as safe as possible. Although the OP dodn't explicately mention it, they're editing wikilinks, which shouldn't have brackets within the content (unless it's recursive, which is unlikely, but the above regex does not check for matching recursive brackets anyway.)

Comment: @Graham If there are no `]` inside `[[...]]`, yes, `[^]]*` will be more efficient. I fall back to lazy dot matching patterns when the right-hand delimiter is a multicharacter string when no specific details are provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess up with regexes, here is a simpler solution.

```
exclusions = ["Special:MyLanguage/:","Category:","File:","Image:"]
# repl_str = "Special:MyLanguage/:"

def replace_str(str, repl_str):
    for ex in exclusions:
        if ex in str:
            return
    str = str[:2] + repl_str + str[2:]
```

Provided they all follow the pattern you provided exactly: [[something]] and they are to be inserted as in your question.

For such a simple case, I find regExes overly complex, especially when using lookaheads, lookbehinds and using capture groups. Keep it simple when you can, save algorithm complexity for when it's really needed, just saying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub` and `re.findall`:

```
import re
tests = ['[[ACBDEF]]', '[[Special:MyLanguage/ACBDEF]]', '[[Category:ACBDEF]]', '[[File:ACBDEF]]', '[[OneLasttest]]']
def isvalid(lang):
  return not re.findall('^Special:MyLanguage/|^File|^Category|^Image', lang)

final_results = [re.sub('(?<=\[\[)[\w\W]+(?=\]\])', '{}', i).format(*['Special:MyLanguage/'+c if isvalid(c) else c for c in re.findall('(?<=\[\[)[\w\W]+(?=\]\])', i)]) for i in tests]
```

Output:

```
['[[Special:MyLanguage/ACBDEF]]', '[[Special:MyLanguage/ACBDEF]]', '[[Category:ACBDEF]]', '[[File:ACBDEF]]', '[[Special:MyLanguage/OneLasttest]]']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a function with `excludes`:

```
import re

excludes = ['Special:MyLanguage', 'Category:', 'File:', 'Image:']

s = "[[Special:MyLanguage/text]]\n[[File:text]]\n[[Image:text]]\n[[Category:text]]\n[[Text and ]]"

def analyze(match):
    for exclude in excludes:
        if exclude in match.group(1):
            return '[[{}]]'.format(match.group(1))
    return '[[Special:MyLanguage/{}]]'.format(match.group(1))

rx = re.compile(r'\[\[(.*?)\]\]')

s = rx.sub(analyze, s)
print(s)
```

This yields

```
[[Special:MyLanguage/text]]
[[File:text]]
[[Image:text]]
[[Category:text]]
[[Special:MyLanguage/Text and ]]
```